# Incorrect address returned by crypt() on Solaris x64

Tags: 64-bit, solaris, crypt

When debugging shared library loaded with `dlopen()`, I found an interesting thing.The address returned by `crypt()` function when called from my library is 32 bits based; that is, when I try to see that address in debugger. it says that this is a bad address. Adding to this address a shift which is in my case `0xffffffff00000000` gives the correct result. Looking at the `crypt` sources it is clear that the string returned by `crypt` is a static char array, but it is not clear why the address is 32 bits based.

Thank you in advance to any ideas and help

Answer (score 1):

Did you `#include <unistd.h>` or `#include <crypt.h>` in your code so that it had the function prototype declaring `crypt()` as returning `char *`?

If you don't have a function prototype, C defaults to assuming functions return `int`, even if that's only 32-bits on a 64-bit machine, and this often breaks functions that return pointers (which work by accident on 32-bit systems where `int` is the same size as a pointer).